# Query about days function in mysql

Tags: mysql, days

My table named as `sales`. It contains the column like the following.

```
fld_id  int(11),
fld_date    date,
fld_state   varchar(45),
fld_dtcode  varchar(45),
fld_companyname varchar(150),
fld_unitrate    int(11),
fld_count   int(11),
fld_amount  int(11),
```

I want to find out the avg of last 30 days sale. 
pls help me to find the average of sale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just use `AVG()`

```
SELECT AVG(fld_amount * fld_count) AvgSales30
FROM sales
WHERE fld_date > Date_Add(curdate(), interval -30 day)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select avg(fld_count*fld_amount) as average
from sales
where fld_date > now() - interval 30 day
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1023b/1)